How to make screen reader announce a dollar value before announcing the value of a text box
 
In my app, i have a text input to get amount value. However, the dollar symbol is given as an image . So, dollar won't be there in text box. Now, when the user tabs to this text box, how can i make the screen reader announce a $ prefix to the value?

Can you include the HTML for a Minimal, Reproducible Example?

<img src='dollar.png/>   - this is the html. i am unable to edit

Add the required alt to your img?

  when the input box is focussed, how to announce the $ as if it is part of the input box? as screen reader only reads what is focussed right?

If you are using an image, that can be accessed as such, you need to provide an alt attribute.
A simple solution then is to use the wrapping-label-technique to provide an accessible name for the input.
That way, the $ will be included in the name.


<label>Amount
    <input type="number">
    <img src="…" alt="$">
</label>



If you can’t use the wrapping technique, you might reference both elements to construct the accessible name.
The for is still recommended so that the browser can focus the input when you click the label.


<label for="amount" id="amount-label">Amount</label>
<input aria-labelledby="amount-label amount-dollar" type="number" id="amount">
<img src="…" alt="$" id="amount-dollar">



You could also use aria-label only, but its contents will need to include the visual label to allow voice control users to target the input and to satisfy Criterion Label in Name.
Another option might be to use description via aria-describedby, but it depends on user settings whether it is being read, and for something short like $ it’s not worth it.
The gov.uk design system, which is a good reference for accessible components, suggests always including the unit in the label.

In that case, the image would not need to be made part of the label, but it would still need an alternative text.

thank you for all the options you have given. We dont have a label as we are expected to use the column header label. However, i will try all your options and will update you.I am on vacation. It may take a few days. or may have to do this in my spare time

In that case you should have aria-labelledby attributes pointing to the table heading already, so you only need to add the reference to the image.

To make a screen reader announce a dollar value before the value of a text box, you can utilize the aria-label attribute in your HTML input element. The aria-label attribute allows you to specify a string to be read by the screen reader that can be different from the text shown visually on the screen. Since your dollar symbol is presented as an image and not included within the text box, you can prepend the dollar sign to the aria-label description of the text box.
Amount:



Thank You @vishnu. Very close to what i want. However, Mac voice over first read the value (say 44) and then reads $44. While NVDA first reads $44 and then reads 44. Looks like that is the closest we can get

Currently this answer suggest a harmful practice and mixes label and description, which are two different things. “can be different from the text shown visually on the screen.”. That’s only within limits, otherwise you’ll fail criterion Label in Name. Setting aria-label will overwrite any label you already have, it’s very important that the actual text label will still be included. This is implied in the word “prepend” but not very clear.
